# Implementing console.table in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, formatting

I just wrote this simple function in order to implement something like `console.table`:

```
function toTable(obj) {
    let arr = '';
    arr += '--------------------------\r\n';
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj[0])) {
        arr += ' ' + key + '\t';
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        arr += '\r\n--------------------------\r\n';
        for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj[i])) {
            arr += ' ' + value + '\t\t';
        }

    }
    arr += '\r\n--------------------------';
    return arr;
}
```

An example with an array of objects:

```
let arr = [
    { firstName: 'Sirwan', lastName: 'Afifi', age: 27 },
    { firstName: 'Person2', lastName: 'P2', age: 32 }
];
```

It gives you following result:

```
--------------------------
 firstName   lastName    age    
--------------------------
 Sirwan      Afifi       27     
--------------------------
 Person2     P2          32     
--------------------------
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would add a condition to check for empty arrays, a fairly common condition. Another common use case is arrays of arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some things that can be improved

- **Naming**:

  - `toTable` is expressive but also confusing. It looks like it is converting something to *table*. When used in conjunction with HTML this could be confused with `<table>`. Adding comments to the function can be helpful to understand what the function is doing. But again, if comments are needed that means you're not naming variables correctly.
  - `obj` the short of object is descriptive when used for naming object. However, for this function it is wrong as the function is expecting an array. `arr` or `array` would be better.
  - `arr` Again, the variable is used to store a string. `str` can be used or some developers even use `str` as prefix e.g. `strTable`, `strLine`.

#### Repetitive Code:

- `'--------------------------\r\n'` is used three times in the code. You can create a variable to store this string value and use it anywhere to add the line of hyphens.

#### `for` loops:

`for` loops is used three times in the code. Nested loops should be avoided. There are very few cases when nested loops are required. Always try to avoid nested loops wherever possible.

In the first loop, the keys of the object are joined using tab character.

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj[0])) {
    arr += ' ' + key + '\t';
}
```

This can be done using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) which returns an array of keys. Then [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) can be used on keys array to join the array elements by *glue*-`\t` in this case.

So, the new code will be

```
Object.keys(arr[0]).join('\t') // That's it!
```

The other nested loop will be slow if object is having large number of properties.

```
for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    arr += '\r\n--------------------------\r\n';
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj[i])) {
        arr += ' ' + value + '\t\t';
    }
}
```

Looking at it carefully shows that this only create a string of values separated by tab. [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) can be used for this. But again, as the objects are inside array, it need to be iterated over and then values can be extracted from object. New code using this function will look like

```
arr.forEach(function(obj) {
    someVar += line + Object.values(obj).join('\t\t'); // Sweet!
});
```

---

Apart from these, below are some suggestions:

- Using `console.table` consistently: If `console.table` is supported by target environment then why not use the beautiful function? Although, this function(`toTable()` from question) is not complete as it doesn't support printing object in table, object containing different keys, nested object, etc. For the basic implementation, it can override default method.

  ```
  if (!console.table) {
      // Use fallback only when not available
      console.table = function(arr) {
          // Code here
      };
  }
  ```
- Creating the horizontal line dynamically.

  The horizontal line is static. In case when the object contain less/more properties, it'll not fit correctly. To create the line dynamically again, `Object.keys()` can be used.

  ```
  '-'.repeat(8 * keys.length) // Assuming a tab(\t) is eight characters long
  ```
- Using *monospace* font to log data

  For *non-monospace* fonts not all characters occupy same space. For example, `i` takes less space than `O`. [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Console/log) can be set with custom font using the second parameter which is CSS styles.

  ```
  console.log('%c' + someString, 'font-family: monospace');
  ```

Here's **code** with these changes

```
if (!console.table) {
    console.table = function(arr) {
        'use strict';

        let keys = Object.keys(arr[0]);
        const horizontalLine = '\r\n' + '-'.repeat(8 * keys.length) + '\r\n';
        let heading = Object.keys(arr[0]).join('\t');

        let str = horizontalLine;
        str += heading;

        arr.forEach(function(obj) {
            str += horizontalLine + Object.values(obj).join('\t\t');
        });
        str += horizontalLine;
        console.log('%c' + str, 'font-family: monospace');
    };
}

let arr = [
    { firstName: 'Sirwan', lastName: 'Afifi', age: 27 },
    { firstName: 'Person2', lastName: 'P2', age: 32 }
];
console.table(arr);
```

Here's [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/aksov6jc/) to try out it.

And here's **output** of the above code

```
------------------------
firstName   lastName    age
------------------------
Sirwan      Afifi       27
------------------------
Person2     P2      32
------------------------
```

**Note:**

1. As some of the features are only available in latest browsers/nodeJS version and some are experimental, see the MDN link embedded for browser support and polyfill.
2. This, by any means is not polyfill for `console.table`. This is just another version of the OP's code. `console.table` is overriden with assumptions that only the provided input format is used to log in table.
3. The horizontal lines are not perfect. They can contain less/more depending on the min and max length of key in the object.

Comment: Cool, I learned stuff. Too bad that your excellent answer is now good competition with my answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question;

- The variable name `arr` is unfortunate, you are not dealing with an array but with a string
- You are copy pasting `'--------------------------\r\n'`, you should either have a constant for this, or, dynamically calculate how long it should be so that the output is always beautiful
- `for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj[0])) {`, why go over `value` if you don't use it?
- Also, consider `Array.join()` which is meant for this kind of situations
- This

  ```
  let arr = '';
  arr += '--------------------------\r\n';
  ```

  should be

  ```
  let arr = '--------------------------\r\n';
  ```

  and in fact, that `\r` looks iffy, unless you have a very specific use case, I would use

  ```
  let arr = '--------------------------\n';
  ```
- It does not make much sense to separate keys with `\t` and values with `\t\t`, why do you do this?
- Same as my 2nd point, why go over `key` in a loop where you don't use `key`?

This is my first counterproposal:

```
function arrayToString( array ){
  return ' ' + array.join(' \t');
}

function toTable2(objectArray) {
    const line = '--------------------------';
    let arr = [line, arrayToString( Object.keys(objectArray[0]) )];

    for (let i = 0; i < objectArray.length; i++) {
      arr.push(line);
      arr.push( ' ' + arrayToString( Object.values( objectArray[i] ) ) );
    }
    arr.push(line);
    return arr.join('\n');
}
```

The output is slightly different, because this outputs keys in the same manner as values. This shows the limits of just placing tabs, if you want a visually pleasing output, then you need the check the length of each column and pad spaces.

You could go a little bit more functional, by realizing that you are parsing every element in a list, so you could use `map`:

```
function toTable3(objectArray) {
    const line = '--------------------------\n';
    let list = [Object.keys(objectArray[0])].concat( objectArray.map( o=>Object.values(o) ) );
    list = list.map( list => arrayToString(list) );

    return line + list.join('\n'+line) + '\n' + line;
}
```

This is my last counter-proposal, it is a tad too dense for me, but it shows some more of the power in `map` and `join`. If this were real production with expected maintenance of the code, then I would spread this out over more lines of code:

```
function toTable4(objectArray){
  //Extract keys
  const keys = Object.keys( objectArray[0] );
  //Build a list with keys and values  
  let list = [keys].concat( objectArray.map( o=>Object.values(o) ) );
  //For each key, get the maximum value or key length, add 1 to space out
  const lengths = keys.map( (key, index) => Math.max.apply(null, list.map( o => (o[index]+'').length ) ) + 1 );
  //Build a line of the right amount of '-'
  const line = '-'.repeat( lengths.reduce( (out,value)=>out+value , 0  ) + 1 )
  //Convert every object to an evenly spaced line with a lines separator
  list = list.map(  o => ' ' + o.map( ( value, index) => value + ' '.repeat( lengths[index] - value.length ) ).join('') + '\n' + line );
  //Return each line separated with a newline, prefixed with one more line
  return line + '\n' + list.join('\n');
}
```